# Id to Entity conversion is not working in Spring Boot 2.2.8 and higher

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I tried to upgrade the Spring Boot version for my application and found a difference in behavior. When switching from 2.2.7 to 2.2.8 (and higher), the conversion from identifier to database entity stops working.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DomainClassConverterTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DomainClassConverterTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initialize(ModelRepository modelRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Stream.of("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model X").forEach(name -> {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setName(name);
                modelRepository.save(model);
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ModelController {
    private final ModelRepository repository;

    public ModelController(ModelRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/models/{id}")
    public Model getModel(@PathVariable("id") Model model) {
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping("/models")
    public Page<Model> findAllModels(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Model() {}

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Model{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + "'}"; }
}
```

After investigation of this problem, I discovered that the root cause of this is in the `DomainClassConverter` class. I understand that the problem lies in the `setApplicationContext` method. The method uses lazy initialization, and it adds converters to `СonversionService`, but only after the first use. But this event never occurs because the converter is not registered in `СonversionService`. Here is the method:

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {

    this.repositories = Lazy.of(() -> {

        Repositories repositories = new Repositories(context);

        this.toEntityConverter = Optional.of(new ToEntityConverter(repositories, conversionService));
        this.toEntityConverter.ifPresent(it -> conversionService.addConverter(it));

        this.toIdConverter = Optional.of(new ToIdConverter(repositories, conversionService));
        this.toIdConverter.ifPresent(it -> conversionService.addConverter(it));

        return repositories;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug [DATACMNS-1743](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1743) and was fixed in 2.2.8, 2.3.2, and higher.